# Does the butter function always produce stable filter coefficients?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, butterworth

I need to design a stable bandpass filter (it can be IIR as well). I used the `butter` function in MATLAB (Signal Processing Toolbox). Now how do I know if my filter is stable? I tried `isstable` (also from the Signal Processing Toolbox). The question is does `butter` always return stable filter coefficients? Whatever parameter or input is given to `butter`, will it always give stable filter coefficients for any condition? Is there a way to know under what condition the filter may not be stable?

Comment: Did you read [this part](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#bucsfmj) of the documentation? The syntax used to call `butter` matters. Please add your code to your question so we may see what syntax you use.

Comment: Butterworth filters are, by construction, [BIBO-stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability) (impulse response absolutely summable). However, as noted by Cris, there may be _numerical_ instability problems that produce a wrong result, and that result is typically BIBO-instable

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the comments. I am using sos now, hopefully my filter is always stable.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Thanks for the comments. I am using sos now, hopefully my filter is always stable.